# ESLint plugin for VSCode doesn't give IDE feedback on files within symlink directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I have a project within a sandbox (linux - centos) that I access from my host (windows 10) machine using the first party Remote - SSH plugin for VSCode from Microsoft.

Within this sandbox I have symlinked directory e.g. `/home/developer/` is symlinked to `/var/www/`

When I use the remote ssh file explorer from VSCode to open my files, they open from the symlink path `/home/developer/` etc, and the ESLint plugin for VSCode will never provide realtime IDE indicators of any linting errors.

Instead, within the problems tab of my console, I get an error for each file I have opened:

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: ../../../../home/developer/html/boilerplate/src/pages/App.vue.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.
```

However, if I open the file in the absolute original path (`/var/www/`, I get the feedback I expect in my problems console:

```
Unexpected console statement.
```

and I also get the real time IDE feedback.

[image: eslint output of original path vs symlink path]

Is there any way to get the ESLint plugin for VSCode to treat the symlink directory in the same manner? I'm not sure why I am getting these differences in behaviour.

I also have an `eslintc.cjs` file, and here are the parser and parserOptions values:

```
parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    sourceType: 'module', // Allows for the use of imports
    extraFileExtensions: ['.vue'],
  },
```

Any help is very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which version of eslint is the plug-in using? https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13551 seems related.